# generating web-service classes using soapUI with a WSDL over HTTPS

Tags: java, web-services, https, soapui

I'm using SoapUI to generate my web service client classes (using wsimport/jax-ws ri if it makes a difference).  I've had no problem with this for several services, however, the one im working on now has a wsdl file which is served via https and I get the following error when I try to generate my client classes.

> [ERROR]
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification
>   path to requested target
>
> Failed to read the WSDL document:
>   https:///service.wsdl,
>   because 1) could not find the
>   document; /2) the document could not
>   be read; 3) the root element of the
>   document is not .
>
> [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not
>   find wsdl:service in the provided
>   WSDL(s):
>
> At least one WSDL with at least one
>   service definition needs to be
>   provided.
>
> ```
>             Failed to parse the WSDL.
> ```

Any idea of what I have to do to resolve this?  I'm assuming somewhere I have to set up security information to allow this request to work?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using soapUI? NetBeans and Eclipse do this pretty well...

Comment: No reason in particular, but there's no reason I shouldn't be able to get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that server certificate is self-signed or otherwise untrusted.

You need to import the server's certificate into your Java keystore. (You can use [this method](https://web.archive.org/web/20110516222654/http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find) if you wish, which looks easier than the last time I tried to do it.)

Alternatively, you can download the WSDL and supporting schemas via a browser and then run wsimport on the local files. (This approach probably won't help when you come to actually invoke the service in question)

Comment: Link broken.  Any idea what method we use to import the server certificate into the Java keystore?

Comment: Hey, plz add the essential parts to the ANSWER, don't give link only answers. This would be enough for answer deletion, by rules of SO.

Comment: The essential part of the answer is that the server is untrusted - not the mechanism for how to import a public certificate chain into the JKS keystore (which is another issue).